# scraping a page

Tags: php, screen-scraping

What would be best practice in scraping a horrible mess of a distributor's inventory page (using js to document.write a <td>, then using plaintext html to close it)? No divs/tds/anything is labelled with any id or classes, etc.

Should I just straight up preg_match(?_all) the thing or is there some xpath magic I can do?
There is no api, no feeds, no xml, nothing clean at all.

edit:

-
What i'm basically thinking of atm is something like http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EuMfRVD5 - is that my best bet or is there any other way?

Comment: You might get more concrete answers if you had an example page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not enough of an example. But since you seemingly don't need the highlighting meta info anyway, the JS-obfuscation could be undone with a bit of:

```
$html = preg_replace('# <script .*? (?: document.write\("(.*?)"\) )? .*? </script> #six', "$1", $html);
```

Maybe that's already good enough to pipe it through one of the DOM libraries afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should always use http://www.php.net/DOM to parse a page.  Regex is horrible and usually downright impossible to use for parsing html, because that's not what it was built for.

However...if the page uses a lot of javascript to output stuff, you are kind of SoL regardless.  The *best* you can really do to get a complete picture is to grab it and run it through a browser and parse what is rendered.  It is possible to automate it, though it's kind of a pita to setup.

But...given the issue w/ js outputting a lot of it...maybe regex really would be best route.  But I guess first and foremost it kind of depends on what the actual content is and what it is you are trying to get from the page.

Comment: Its pretty much some inane stuff like http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ws9rKxNX , I just need to pull the html in between that script tag and that ending td. For some insane reason, spacing is completely randomized, so I'm really considering just str_replacing large amounts of that tag to remove all the surrounding JS and then dumping that class into a variable

Comment: He did not ask about parsing, but extracting. The recitation of the regex-html-parsing fallacy is probably redundant if it's the best option in this case anyway. @jae: That looks intentionally obfuscated.

Comment: It's not intentionally obfuscated, just stupidly coded probably..  "33409584" is the part # and that's apparently how they highlight the part number in the table

Comment: In search results there's basically a huge table and every cell/row uses partnumber == partnumber to check if it should be highlighted, which is just mindboggling

Comment: @mario: you're just nitpicking about semantics.  Point is that he is wanting to get information from a DOM structured string, which makes a DOM parser the best tool for the job in most cases.

Comment: @jmoon: I do however agree with mario that judging from the code from your pastebin, they are intentionally obfuscating it, most likely to make it harder for people like you to scrape their page ;)